# Developing two projects with bower

Tags: build, dependencies, grunt-wiredep

I have Project A (a full blown web app), and Project B - a component project used by Project A.
Project A uses bower to define a dependency on Project B.

The goal in a nutshell - I want to be able to develop both A and B simultaneously, so that when the sources of B change, A will be notified, and these changes will be reflected in the browser right away.
The problem seems to be that I can't find a convenient way to define the dependency of A on B's sources, rather than it's wrapped up artifacts.

In A's index.html, I need to somehow include the very final artifacts provided by B. Namely, it would be something like project_b.js and project_b.css.

These artifacts are the final products of B - they are the result of building the sources.
In B's bower.json file, then, I need to define these artifacts under the "main" section.

I also use grunt-bower-install / grunt-wiredap in order to properly orchestrate all bower dependencies into A's index.html. A tool of this kind will eventually work with the files defined in B's "main" section.

But what happens in dev mode?
Ideally, in dev mode I could change the code of the source of B, and see it reflected in A.
bower link solves only a part of the problem, since in order for A to really react to the changes in B's source, I will have to initiate a build a in B, that will change the project's "main" artifacts, and only then will A really be affected.

That's not convenient IMO.
In dev mode, I usually work against source files, and avoid continuously building (up to some minor tasks, such as jshint, compass, etc.).
I would like to also work against the source files of B...
This is also important with regard to debugging.

Do you have an idea of how to achieve this?
I have some tricks in mind, but I'm not sure they'd really work.

Thank you very much in any case,
Daniel